# Template inheritance from base class and return types

Tags: c++, templates, return-type, template-inheritance

i have some problems with my project. Here is some code:

```
class calcDinamica
{
public:
    virtual void somma() =0;
    virtual void creaPrimo() =0;
    virtual T* ritornaPrimo()const{cout<<"errore"<<endl;};//THIS is what i want
    virtual ~calcDinamica(){};
};

template<class T>
class calcolatrice:public calcDinamica
{
private:
    T* primoVett;  //first operand
    T* secondoVett; //second operand
    T* risultatoVett; //result
public:
    calcolatrice():primoVett(0), secondoVett(0), risultatoVett(0){};
    virtual void creaPrimo(){primoVett= new T;};
    virtual void creaSecondo(){secondoVett= new T;};
    virtual void creaRisultato(){};
    virtual void somma()
    {
        risultatoVett=new T;
        *risultatoVett=*primoVett+*secondoVett;
    };
    virtual T* ritornaPrimo()const{cout<<"giusto"<<endl;return primoVett;};
};
```

This code is for a calculator, i have other 3 different classes, and these classes i posted above are only to keep track of the data i create during the session, since i am implementing this with QT.

So, i created this base CalcDinamica only to permit me to have a pointer like calcDinamica* cal; and then creating it like: calc= new calcolatrice < matrix > , because when i am using the calculator with QT, i can change the type of operands that i want to operate(like vectors or matrix).

Ok, this works, but i want to return the data inside calcolatrice , without doing a lot of dynamic_cast with the pointer of calcDinamica. 
How can i make it, or is it impossible? Because if it's impossible, i better leave this option of the base class, and just create 3 differents calcolatrice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add "`template<class T>`" before "`class calcDinamica`" and add "`<T>`" after "`class calcolatrice:public calcDinamica`"

Comment: Thx, but no, if i do like this, the purpose of the base class will be lost, and it become useless. The only purpose of that pure base class is that i can declare a pointer with no T type, like: calcDinamica* test; and then when i know what type i want to use, i create the new item with   test=new calcolatrice < matrix > for example. Then, if i use test->somma(); it works, but i can't find a way to retrieve the data inside without doing a dynamic_cast on "test" pointer. I want to find a way to have a similar method like somma(), able to give me back the private data of calcolatrice.

Comment: ok, I know. Try 'class calcDinamica
{
public:
    virtual void somma() =0;
    virtual void creaPrimo() =0;
    template<typename T> virtual T* ritornaPrimo()const{cout<<"errore"<<endl;};//THIS is what i want
    virtual ~calcDinamica(){};
};'

Comment: I already tried it, sadly: error: templates may not be 'virtual'. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with multiple types, you must implement a single base class for expressions of all types and use that in the AST, and perform type checking on all expressions evaluated.